# Reload tableview iphone developer

Tags: iphone, cell, tableview

I have a feed reader that read automatically the homepage of my website! But when I change the feed URL and reload data the cell isn't reloaaded! Infact I must scroll the cell view (infact with this action is called the didselectrowatindex method) to reload data in the cell with the new ones.
I tried [tableview reload]; without any results....
Is there a method to reload all content in the cell without scrolling it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be [tableview reloadData]

If it's not working, then maybe you have a problem with your IBOutlet?

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to say without seeing the source.  Generally speaking, the only common issues I can think of are: making sure the cells have all been made visible already and making sure you're actually calling the reloadData method on the right object.  As a debugging technique, you could put an NSLog in your cellForRowAtIndex method, to make sure that the reload method is actually calling it.